# Function not updating internal state of mt19937

Tags: c++, random, mt19937

I have a function that generates and writes random integers:

```
void randint(int min, int max, int times,std::mt19937 rng){

    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(min, max);

    for (int i=0;i<times;i++){
        std::cout<<dist(rng)<<' ';
    }
}
```

When this function is called, generates numbers from the `mt19937` object. However, when returning from the function, the `mt19937` object's internal state is not updated.

This can be seen by running this code below.

```
int main(){
    std::mt19937 gen(2845);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> spread(1,100);

    randint(1,100,5,gen);

    std::cout<<"| ";

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        std::cout<<spread(gen)<<' ';
    }
```

Actual Output:

```
88 93 79 43 92 | 88 93 79 43 92
```

Expected output:

```
88 93 79 43 92 | 97 71 34 32 70
```

Is there any way for the internal state to be continuously updated even when passed through the function?

Comment: Your function accepts the generator by value so the operations inside the function are working on a copy. You should pass it by reference.

Comment: Try passing it by reference: `std::mt19937 & rng`.

Comment: Not sure if there's a better duplicate target for C++. Seems like there should be, this is a reasonably common source of confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the object by value (i.e. you are copying the object when you call the function). Use a reference

```
void randint(int min, int max, int times,std::mt19937& rng){
```